# enhancing a program - complete failure

Tags: c++, file, text

good day everyone. 
im having some trouble trying to figure out how to enhance my program.

here's the question:

Write a program to compute numeric grades for a course. The course records are in a file that will serve as the input file. The input file is in exactly the following format: Each line contains a student’s last name, then one space, then the student’s first name, then one space, then ten quiz scores all on one line. The quiz scores are whole numbers and are separated by one space. Your program will take its input from this file and send its output to a second file. The data in the output file will be the same as the data in the input file except that there will be one additional number (of type double) at the end of each line. This number will be the average of the student’s ten quiz scores. If this is being done as a class assignment, obtain the file names from your instructor. Use at least one function that has file streams as all or some of its arguments.

i managed to do the first part successfully. below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream infile("grades.txt",ios::in);
    if(!infile){cerr<<"file could not be found!";exit(1);}

    fstream outfile("average.txt",ios::out);
    if(!outfile){cerr<<"file could not be created!";exit(1);}


    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int grades[10];
    char c;
    int x;
    cout<<"how many students?";
    cin>>x;

        for(int k=0;k<x;k++)
        {
            infile>>fname;
            infile>>lname;
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            infile>>grades[i];
            outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" ";
            double sum=0;
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++) 
            {

                outfile<<grades[j]<<" ";
                sum+=grades[j];

            }

            double avg=0;
            avg=sum/10;
            outfile<<avg<<endl;
        }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

im not able to do part (a) of the second part. i tried initializing the grades[10] array to zeros, but im not getting any correct output. any help? thank you.

> Enhance the program you wrote for (Problem 10) in all the following
>   ways.
>
> a-The list of quiz scores on each line will contain ten of fewer quiz
>   scores. (If there are fewer than ten quiz       scores, that means
>   that the student missed one or more quizzes.) The average score is
>   still the sum of the      quiz scores divided by 10. This amounts to
>   giving the student a 0 for any missed quiz.
>
> b-The output file will contain a line (or lines) at the beginning of
>   the file explaining the output. Use     formatting instructions to
>   make the layout neat and easy to read. c- After placing the desired
>   output in an output file, your program will close all files and then
>   copy the     contents of the “output” file to the  “input”  file so
>   that the net effect is to change the contents of the input     file.
>   Use at least two functions that have file streams as all or some of
>   their arguments. If this is being done as a    class assignment,
>   obtain the file names from your instruction.

---

here's how my code looks now

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream infile("grades.txt",ios::in);
    if(!infile){cerr<<"file could not be found!";exit(1);}

    fstream outfile("average.txt",ios::out);
    if(!outfile){cerr<<"file could not be created!";exit(1);}


    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int grades;
    int sum=0;
    int linecount=0;
    char c;

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
            infile>>lname;
            infile>>fname;
            outfile<<lname<<" "<<fname<<" ";
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){if(infile>>grades)outfile<<grades<<" ";else {outfile<<"0 ";break;} sum+=grades;}
            outfile<<double(sum/10.0);
    }
            system("pause");
            return 0;
}
```

but im getting just a black space when i run the program. im not able to fix the loop to read from all the lines of the file.

Comment: hint: you dont need to initialize your array with zeros. you dont even need the grades-array ;) Your solution is not the optimal one but it is working so far. You should think about how to detect if there are less than 10 grades in the current line. Maybe the break-statement ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w(v=vs.80).aspx ) will help (the most elegant solution would also need no break but it might help). Another issue: be careful with dividing by just `10` because it will do an integer-division and not a double-division. Try `/10.0` or `/10f` instead

Comment: how am i going to process the grades and get the average if i dont have a grades array?

Comment: you are just loading the next grade, add to the sum and read the next grade, ... the information is then inside your sum: `while(<next grade exists>){sum += readNextGrade();} avg = sum/10.0` or `for(int j=0;j<10;j++){int curGrade = <readNextGrade>; if(<error occured>) break; sum+=curGrade} avg=sum/10.0`

Comment: i dont think this can be done coz the contents of the file is Jackson Tom 95 97 94 87 67 84 99 45 99 87
Jackson Michael 43 23 34 77 64 35 89 56 75 85
Johnson Sara 84 93 64 57 89 99 74 64 75 35 91

Comment: ok i managed to fix that thank u

Comment: it is possible to calculate the average "on-the-fly" without storing all ten grades. But it is not possible to calculate the variance on-the-fly for instance.

Comment: how do i make a loop for the lines?

Comment: take a look at the ifstream ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ ). There are useful functions for processing file input line by line and checking erros, endOfFile (eof), etc (inherited from `istream` and `ios`).

Comment: General C++ advice: If your code contains magic literals like `10` or `20`, You're Doing It Wrong :-)

Comment: when im using the loop while(!infile.eof()){....} im getting a black space when i run the program.

Comment: ' while(!infile.eof())
 {
   infile>>lname;
   infile>>fname;
   outfile<<lname<<" "<<fname<<" ";
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){if(infile>>grades)outfile<<grades<<" ";else {outfile<<"0 ";break;} sum+=grades;}
   outfile<<double(sum/10.0);
 }'

Answer (score 2):

As of the first part: Your code doesn't exactly solve the problem as given. The problem as given doesn't say you enter a number of students, but you should process all students in the file, no matter how many they are. Also, you neglected the part: "Use at least one function that has file streams as all or some of its arguments."

Anyways, I'd advise you to read the file line by line, and then process each line individually using `ostringstream`. That way, detecting that no more grades follow works the same way as detecting that no more students follow in part 1.

Hint: Look at the stream error status, especially `fail`, and use a `while` loop in part 1, and `break` in part 2.